# Amazon IAM User + Granting Access to S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a couple of questions about an IAM User and granting access to S3.

Note: I'm using S3.php to write files with this users.

1. Can the user have a Password set?
2. After creating the user (have done) should I use a group or user policy to grant access?
3. I only want this user to be able to write objects (have bucket policy giving global public read). how can I grant just this right? (user policy) and are other rights need to put files in the bucket?

thx

Answer (score 3):

Point-by-point:

1. "**Can the user have a Password set?**" The user can have a password set, though for API access I do not believe a password can be used directly. Nothing about having a password set *prevents* API access.
2. "**should I use a group or user policy to grant access?**" The distinction between user vs group policies is just a matter of organisation. If several of your users require access "for the same reason", then it makes sense to create a group policy. If every user has a specific set of requirements, for reasons which do not overlap, then individual user-policies make more sense. It's basically a question of future administration: If the policy requirements changed in the future, would you be more likely to need to make the same change across multiple users, or to make various individual changes?
3. "**I only want this user to be able to write objects**" The policy generator can help with this, but the key things you need to know are:

   - The type of action you're looking for is "s3:PutObject". Depending on what you actually mean by "write", you may need a couple of other permissions as well: "s3:DeleteObject" and "s3:ListBucket" are common extras.
   - The "arn" would be: ""arn:aws:s3:::bucketNameGoesHere/*", or replace the asterisk with something more-specific to limit "puts" to a given prefix"

Below, I have included a basic policy which might do what you want. I expect it will require some tweaking to be exactly what you need:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AnyUniqueIdentifierForThePolicyStatementGoesHere",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::YourBucketNameGoesHere/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Hopefully that is at least enough to point you in the right direction.

useful links:

- http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html
- http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucketPolicies.html